# iOS re-asking for permission to contacts

Tags: ios, contacts, abaddressbook

I am just double checking that you cant ask for permissions to access contacts if a user has already said no.

I know you can detect if you have access and then just prompt the user to go to settings and enable access.  I just wondered if you can re-ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cant. Actually this is controlled by the operating system. There is no need to ask twice. When a user does not want to allow access anymore he can go to settings and disable address book access for your app.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.
The user will be prompt again 1 day later "if" he reinstall the app or something like that.
It belongs to the system, so if the user said no, you can't do anything